# How can i get merge cell info from xlsb

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsb

I use POI to read xlsb file. But i can't get the merge cell info.

I use the module in this page. Please review below source code file path

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/TestXSSFBReader.java

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to handle merge cells.
You can find the info of record type number in the following doc:
https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-XLSB/[MS-XLSB]-160929.pdf.
They are:
BrtMergeCell(176),
BrtBeginMergeCells(177),
BrtEndMergeCells(178).
And add those in XSSFBRecordType. But this class is an internal class in POI, you can create the same class and add those class. 
Finally, you should add a handle function in XSSFSheetHandler : handleRecord( ).